# Mongo response time monitor

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to monitor the response time since mongo got a command to execute till the returned an answer?
I couldn't find any in MMS nor in Server Density?
Is there other service that can give me that information?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB profiling: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler should be able to profile your queries for you and tell you what the response times were.

The default setting is `2` like so:

```
db.setProfilingLevel(2);
```

Which will write all operations to `db.system.profile`. You also have `1` for more precise testing for slow queries.